# Linting for SPM Package.swift file

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

Is there any tool available that is able to lint the Swift Package Manager `Package.swift` file of a library?

I am asking for a similar tool that is available for CocoaPods podspecs through the `pod lib lint` command.

I think the [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) tool doesn't offer this functionality?